# What is the distribution of a normal squared subtract a normal squared?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

What is the distribution of $Z^2-Z'^2$ where $Z \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $Z'\sim N(0,\sigma'^2)$? 
 
I was thinking maybe you could write $(Z-Z')(Z+Z')$ so then you get a product of two normals but then I'm not too sure how to write it as a single distribution.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can find its mean and variance if you assume $Z$ and $Z'$ are independent.  If $\sigma^2 \not = \sigma'^2$ then it will be asymmetric.  I doubt it has a name.

Comment: This difference is a [linear combination of Gamma variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+linear+combination+gamma).